# How to retrieve user mail and name? (PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions, swift 1.2)

Tags: facebook, swift

I have successfully logged my user in, using the following code and plenty of reading on stackoverflow:

```
@IBAction func FBlogin(sender: UIButton) {

    self.activity.startAnimating()

    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            self.activity.stopAnimating()
            if user.isNew {
                print(user.email)
                print(user.username)
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            } else {
                print(user.email)
                print(user.username)
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
            }
        } else {
            self.activity.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

}
```

1. This creates a new user in parse.com BUT does not fill-in email, username ...?

**QUESTION: how does one retrieve the email and userName details?**

AFTER searching and fiddling more I added this code:

```
func getUserDataFromFacebookProfile(user: PFUser)
{

    var facebookid : String?
    var username  : String?
    var userEmail : String?
    var userGender : String?
    var userLocation : String?


    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("graphrequest error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            //if this works, we can store user name und PFUser and mail in    PFuser....
            //not working yet
            /*

            id
            name
            first_name
            last_name
            link
            gender
            locale
            timezone
            updated_time
            verified


            */

            facebookid = result.valueForKey("id") as? String
            userEmail = result.valueForKey("email") as? String
            username = result.valueForKey("name") as? String
            let fname = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? String
            let lname = result.valueForKey("last_name") as? String
            let loc = result.valueForKey("locale") as? String
            let gend = result.valueForKey("gender") as? String


            //userGender = result.valueForKey("gender") as? String
            userLocation = result.valueForKey("location") as? String

            print("*****************************************************************************")
            print("")
            print("graphrequest result  \(facebookid), \(username), \(userEmail), \(gend), \(fname), \(lname)")
            print("")
            print("*****************************************************************************")


        }

        //persist in our DB for later
        let thisUser: PFUser = user

        print("updating current user")
        if let uName = username {
            thisUser.username = uName
        }

        if let uEmail = userEmail {
            thisUser.email = uEmail
        }

        thisUser.saveInBackground()
    })
}
```

The strange thing is that I can only retrieve id, email and name?!

Answer (score 0):

About email: Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

About username: That field is no longer available since v2.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Answer (score 0):

So here is what worked for me. Appparently FB has again changed a few things. The key is to add the required fields to the parameter list, like so:

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:  "me", parameters: ["fields": "email,first_name,last_name,gender,picture.width(480).height(480)"])
```